# Proving the image of a convex polyhedron under a linear map is a polyhedron

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-geometry

I came across the following problem asking me to prove for $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and a convex polyhedron $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that the set
$$
A(Q) = \{ y = Ax \mid x \in Q \}
$$
is also a convex polyhedron. However, I am asked to do so using the following statement about convex polyhedra (which is easy to prove):
\begin{equation}
P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m+n} \text{ is a polyhedron } \implies \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid (x,y) \in P \text{ for some } y \in \mathbb{R}^m \}. ~~~~(1)
\end{equation}
This seems like it should be easy but I'm having trouble.

One approach is to write $Q$ as a set of linear inequalities $$
Q = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Bx \le b \}
$$
and then try to write $A(Q)$ as as system of linear inequalities
$$
A(Q) = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid B\,A^{-1}\, y \le b \}.
$$
This doesn't quite work since $A$ may not be invertible. More importantly, it does not use the statement (#1) given above. Any useful suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you are looking for *Fourier-Motzkin elimination*.

Comment: Can I ask you how to prove the statement 1, i.e. the fact that the projection of a polyhedral set Is Still a polyhedral set, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Statement $(1)$ tells us the projection maps (over any variables) take polyhedral to polyhedral.

Now set  $$P=\{(x,y)  :~  Bx \leq b , ~ y=Ax\}$$

Clearly $P$ is polyhedral. Now observe that the projection map $(x,y) \to y$ takes $P$ to $A(Q)$. Therefore $ A(Q) $ is a polyhedral.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how it's clear that $P$ is a polyhedron. The constraints now include $y \le Ax$ and $y \ge Ax$ for an uncountable number of $x$'s. Also, the contraint $y \le Ax$ and $y \ge Ax$ is incompatible with the constraint $y \le Ax'$ and $y \ge Ax'$ for $x \not= x'$.

Comment: @ted $x,y$ are variables. Why do you treat $y$ as RHS constant !!!

Comment: I thought that convex polyhedrons were defined in the following way: $P = \{ x \mid Ax \le b \}$ where $A$ and $b$ are constants. In fact, Wolfram's Mathworld defines polyhedra as "A convex polyhedron can be formally defined as the set of solutions to a system of linear inequalities".

Comment: @ted  yes that's the definition.  And it is really easy to represent $P$ in standard format  $$P= \{z \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m : ~ C z \leq d \}$$  for some matrix $C$ and vector $d$. Here $z= (x,y)$

Comment: Right, so if that's the definition, then I'm not sure why it's clear that $P = \{(x,y) : Bx \le b, y = Ax \}$ is a polyhedron, since this definition does not match the form $\{ z : Cz \le d \}$. I'm perfectly comfortable with letting $z = (x,y)$. That's not confusing me. The part that is confusing me is that in the standard description, a polyhedron is described by a system of linear inequalities (with constants like $C$ and $d$), whereas in your description, we have variables on the right and left hand side. I guess we can rewrite this as $\{ (x,y) : y - Ax \le 0, Ax - y \le 0, Bx \le b \}$ ?

Comment: Okay, this solves it then. Thanks!